# How to get Beyond Compare to handle .hgtags files correctly?

Tags: mercurial, beyondcompare, .hgtags

We recently switched from P4Merge to BeyondCompare for working with our Hg repositories.

With P4Merge, when you merged branches, there was always a conflict in .hgtags, but just letting P4Merge do it's default action resulted in the correct merged .hgtags.

With BeyondCompare - it seems to just take one of the .hgtags, and not merge any of the differences.  This results in loosing LOTS of tags.

How can we configure BeyondCompare to actually merge the changes for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Using Beyond Compare 4.1.9 and Mercurial 3.7.3 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04, running hg merge after a pull and update for a conflicted .hgtags launched the .hgtags files in Beyond Compare's Text Merge and allowed me to merge them. It's possible there's an issue with your .hgrc configuration.

Here's the .hgrc that worked for diff and merge on my Ubuntu system:

```
[extensions]
# uncomment these lines to enable some popular extensions
# (see "hg help extensions" for more info)
#
# pager =
# progress =
# color =
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.bcomp = bcompare
opts.bcomp = -ro

[merge-tools]
bcomp.executable = bcompare
bcomp.args = $local $other $base $output
bcomp.priority = 1
bcomp.premerge = True
bcomp.gui = True

[ui]
merge = bcomp
```

If you're using Windows or Mac, please let me know.